# Powershell Regex to match everything after the first occurrence of a string

Tags: regex, powershell

So i am having a script in Powershell, this script downloads a list of users from AD and then exports it to a CSV file.
The code is as follows:

```
$AllADUsers | Select-Object @{Label = "First Name";Expression = {$_.GivenName}},
@{Label = "Last Name";Expression = {$_.Surname}},
@{Label = "Password Last Set";Expression = {"Password last set: "+$_.passwordlastset}},
@{Label = "Expiration date";Expression = {"Expires on: "+[datetime]::fromfiletime($_.accountexpires[0])}}, 
@{Label = "OU";Expression = {$_.DistinguishedName}} |
 Export-Csv -Path $csvfile -Encoding "UTF8"  -NoTypeInformation
```

What i need to do here in *DistinguishedName* which is like:

> CN=Test,OU=Test,OU=Test,OU=Test,OU=Test,DC=Test,DC=Test

To remove everything from CN to the first comma and keep only

> OU=Test,OU=Test,OU=Test,OU=Test,DC=Test,DC=Test

I have tried using a regular expression, but i can't figure out how to match only the first occurrence of *,OU=* and keep all that's after it.
I have managed to do it but it keeps removing the OU, and so for that i would need to add an "OU=" string in front of all the DistinguishedNames but this can't be done without a loop and i can't create a Loop inside the *Select-Object* 
I have also tried to remove all the text from DistinguishedName before the Select-Object, but then i would not be able to use an Index inside Select-Object to provide the correct DistinguishedName for the current user.

So i would need a Regex that keeps everything after the first *OU=* and keeps this *OU=* without removing it.

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean you need [`$s -replace '^CN=[^,]*,'`](https://regex101.com/r/aNAQKD/1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a simple regex:

```
@($_.DistinguishedName -split '(?<!\\),',2)[1]
```

The regex pattern can be broken down as:

```
(?<!   # negative lookbehind group
  \\   # for a literal backslash \
)      # end group
,      # literal comma ,
```

the reason for including the lookbehind is that DN's where the RDN contains a comma would otherwise be split on (imagine `CN=Doe\, John,OU=SomeOrgUnit,DC=domain,DC=tld`)

Comment: You are my savior literally!
If it's not asking too much, could you explain me the regex?

Comment: @GriseldIslamaj updated the answer with a brief explanation

Answer (score 1):

You are really asking about parsing distinguished names, which are not really simple strings due to certain characters that require escaping.

Your question is really, "How do I remove the leaf and get only the parent part of a distinguished name?"

For that, you can use the `IADsPathname` interface that Windows provides. This interface is provided to scripts via the `Pathname` COM object.

A while back I wrote a [PowerShell module](https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/PowerShell-ADName) that provides a cmdlet interface to the `Pathname` object that makes it easy to call. In your case, you can use the `Get-ADName` cmdlet and simply write:

```
Get-ADName "CN=Test,OU=Test,OU=Test,OU=Test,OU=Test,DC=Test,DC=Test" -Format Parent
```

This command produces this output:

```
OU=Test,OU=Test,OU=Test,OU=Test,DC=Test,DC=Test
```

As a calculated property in your scenario, you could simply add the following:

```
@{Label = "OU"; Expression = {Get-ADName $_.DistinguishedName -Format Parent}}
```

The `Get-ADName` script cmdlet is pretty handy and saves a lot of work in string parsing of distinguished names.

(As an aside, The module also has the `Convert-ADName` script cmdlet that implements the `NameTranslate` COM object, which lets you convert object names between different formats.)

I find that the `Get-ADName` and `Convert-ADName` script cmdlets are nearly indispensable in a wide variety of scenarios.

Comment: The problem is i can reach this result even with a normal loop or via string manipulation, but i have to do it inside the Select-Object, that's why i need a regex that does it in the moment without having to do any assignment or calling any command.

Comment: I don't understand your qualification. You are already using calculated properties.